# Well-posedness for ODEs with discontinuous right hand side

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, measure-theory

Consider the IVP for ODE with discontinuous right hand side,

\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{y}&=&f(y,y) \quad \quad \text{for }t>0,\\
y(0)&=&y_0,
\end{eqnarray}
where, $f\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{R})$ and $\sup\limits_{x\in \mathbb{R}} {|f(x,\cdot)|_{Lip}< \infty}.$
A natural candidate for the weak solutions is
\begin{eqnarray}
y(t)=y_0+\int\limits_0^t f(y(s),y(s))ds.
\end{eqnarray}
Clearly $y\in C([0,\infty))$ and satisfies the ODE in the sense of distribution.
Is this weak formulation for IVP well-posed? 
Do we need additional regularity assumptions like $F(\cdot,c)$ piecewise constant to prove the uniqueness?
P.S. : A typical example of  of ODE with discontinuous right hand side can be $f(y,y)=\lfloor y \rfloor y$ where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function.

I understand that the problem in general may admit multiple weak solutions. For example the initial value problem $\dot{y}=\frac{1}{2y}$ and $y(0)=0$ admits multiple soltions; namely $y=0$ and $y(t)=\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: Explore $\dot x = -{\rm sign}(x)$ or $\ddot x+x = -{\rm sign}(\dot x)$. There is a problem with the existence of local solutions at discontinuity points. Also the name Fillippov could be important.

Comment: @LutzLehmann could you please elaborate a bit

Comment: Use the [Search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+%22filippov%22). The version of the name with one L seems to be more popular. I believe to have also seen it [with 2 L](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+%22fillippov%22) on a book title page.